# Need your help on responsive page

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-tables

I'm trying to create a responsive website which has layout as below

[image: Mockup for responsive page]

1. On the desktop, there are 2 column, first for introduction and second for login form (or main content), they are same height
2. On the smaller screen, there is only 1 column, with main content at above and introduction section at below.

I created a DOM

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="welcome">
        <span>Welcome to my page</span>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="header">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used `display:table` and `display:table-cell` for Desktop and everything worked well, however I don't know how to display on the smaller screen as the mockup

Please give me any suggestions.

Comment: Use Media Queries to detect screen width and branch CSS.

Comment: use display:inline-block; instead of table-cell.

Comment: Thanks @ShivanRaptor, of course, I had to use media query for detection the screen width, however I didn't know how to put the introduction section under the content section.

Comment: Hi @C-Link, with `display:inline-block`, do you know how to make 2 divs have same height? I tried already however no idea for that

Comment: define width and height for both div and then for smaller screen it goes to below with the same height.

Comment: if you can get away with defining width and height for both blocks, then just arrange html so that it will naturally work for mobile, and for desktop, use float left/right to put them in the correct spots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use

1) **`Flexbox`**, to reverse column order. According to caniuse.com[[http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox]](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), it's got decent support i.e. if you're okay with opera mini users missing out, but keep in mind its global usage is only 2.85%.

CSS

```
.page {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    }

@media (max-width:500px) {
    .page {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        }
    }
```

Demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/7218862

Recommended reading regarding flexbox: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

2) **`Display: Table`**. This has much better support (http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20table), even supported in Opera Mini from version 5 onward. The only downside is you need to have extra wrappers elements around .welcome & .main. Small price to pay.

Markup:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class='bottom'>
        <div class="welcome">
            <span>Welcome to my page</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='top'>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="header">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .page {
        display: table;
        }
    .top {
        display: table-header-group; 
        }
    .bottom {
        display: table-footer-group;
        }
    }
```

Demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/7219553

Here's an article with more information http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2012/11/20/vertical-reordering-of-blocks-with-css-or-how-to-swap-two-elements-using-css/